# Proper way of removing element from array of pointers

Tags: c++

Please take a look at this function :

```
void Remove(char *code){

      for (int i = 0; i < _curSize; i++){
          if (strcmp(code, products[i]->getCode()) == 0){
              delete products[i]; // delete product if found
              products[i] = NULL; // reset a pointer
              products[i] = new Product(); // create new 'default' product 
              products[i] = products[_curSize-1]; // copy product at last index at place of deleted product
             // delete products[_curSize-1]; // if this command gets exe, program crashes. 
              products[_curSize-1] = NULL; //
              _curSize -= 1;
              return;
          }
        }
```

So I guess its pretty clear what I try to do. Based on code delete the product from array of product pointers and then place the last product in place of one deleted. I marked where program crashes. If I comment that line it works fine, but isn't that leaked memory? Note that this is for school, so I have to use pointers.

Comment: _"So I guess its pretty clear what I try to do."_ Nope, not at all.

Comment: You have array of pointers to Product objects. Those products have code attribute. You give this function a code of object you want to remove.

Comment: You have three successive assignments to `products[i]`. Why?

Comment: @nhrnjic6 Best advice I can give is: Simply don't use `new` and `delete` yourself, just use the appropriate [standard container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [Smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) respectively.

Comment: Yes, and `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Comment: you did read this is for school right? meaning I must use pointers. And what if I want to learn more about pointers, memory, and similar stuff. What you are saying is no one should ever use pointers. So if no one should use them why are they still around?

Comment: I think it is perfectly clear what nhrnjic6 is **trying** to do.  Just unclear what confusion caused the inclusion of `products[i] = new Product();` and `delete products[_curSize-1];`  I assume the point is learning about pointers.  So the suggestion to not use pointers isn't actually constructive.

Comment: @nhrnjic6 _"What you are saying is no one should ever use pointers. "_ Basically yes, unless you're absolutely sure you need to. Unfortunately there's a different course taught at many schools, and teachers are outdated about modern C++, and what should be [taught at beginners courses](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/i-have-dream-im-dreaming-of-so-called-c.html).

Comment: @nhrnjic6 If a school doesn't even allow you to use `std::string`, then you're being taught `C`, not C++ and IMO, being ripped off.

Comment: It is allowed but not in this semester. God I hate posting questions about pointers, it seems that unwritten rule of SO is to hate pointers.

Comment: @nhrnjic6 *It is allowed but not in this semester* -- Stroustrup introduces `std::string` immediately to the C++ student:  http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf   Second, if a course really wanted to teach pointers and dynamic memory allocation, at least teach it where there is worth in it.  Example:  Creating your own string class or vector class, where you can use these classes in subsequent problems.  Instead, they teach how to throw around `new[] /  delete[]` all over an application with no coherence.  That is the worst in learning how to use pointers correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This step seems to have no purpose other than creating a memory leak:

```
          products[i] = new Product(); // create new 'default' product
```

This step transfers implied ownership of an object:

```
          products[i] = products[_curSize-1]; // copy product at last index at place of deleted product
```

So this step would not fix a memory leak.  It would cause a crash (as you already know it does):

```
delete products[_curSize-1];
```

Looking at the whole thing:

```
void Remove(char *code){

      for (int i = 0; i < _curSize; i++){
          if (strcmp(code, products[i]->getCode()) == 0){
              delete products[i];          // A correct/important step
              products[i] = NULL;          // Totally useless, but not harmful
//            products[i] = new Product(); // Useless and harmful, creates a memory leak
              products[i] = products[_curSize-1]; // A correct/important step
//            delete products[_curSize-1]; // Very harmful: program crashes. 
              products[_curSize-1] = NULL; // Maybe useful, anyway not harmful.
              _curSize -= 1;               // A correct/important step
              return;
          }
        }
```

Comment: so.. I need to delete object I want to remove and than point to another object like this : delete products[i]; products[i] = products[curSize-1]; ?

Comment: Those are the key steps, together with `_curSize -= 1;`.  Your extra `products[_curSize-1] = NULL;` might be just being careful, or might be necessary (depending on code elsewhere).  Anyway it didn't hurt.  The extra `products[i] = NULL;` has no benefit, but does no harm.